# タグ名変更の提案: reactiveprogramming → reactive-programming

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの付け替えの提案

とても小さい提案ですが、タグ [reactiveprogramming](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactiveprogramming) を本家 Stack Overflow に合わせて [reactive-programming](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactive-programming) へ名称変更したいです。本家のタグ解説ページは[こちらです](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactive-programming/info)。

単にタグをつけかえようとしたところ「不可能です、メタに投稿してください」と出たのでメタに投稿しました。

[image: タグつけかえをしようとしたときに出てきたメッセージです]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

よく似たタグを新規に作成するのを防ぐ仕組みのようですね。
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277679/286934
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/193340/286934

[reactiveprogramming](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactiveprogramming) から [reactive-programming](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactive-programming) に名称変更、もといマージしておきました。