# タグの変更がしたい: circle-ci → circleci

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの付け替えの提案

タグ [circleci](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circleci) が無かったので作成しようとした所、手癖で circle-ci と打ってしまい、タグ [circle-ci](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circle-ci) が作成されました。あわてて circleci に戻そうとしたところ「既に circle-ci が存在している」ことを理由に作成が拒否され、それでも作成したい場合はメタに投稿するよう促されました。

Travis CI と異なり CircleCI には間にスペースが無く、また、本家 Stack Overflow において circle-ci ではなく circleci に[なっている](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circleci)ため、できればハイフン無しの circleci にしたいです。

お手数おかけして申し訳ないのですが、変更に賛同して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 「賛同」はこの質問にup voteするだけでOKでしょうか？

Comment: @cubick さん、はい、それで充分です。過去にもタグの変更をお願いした[ときがある](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2558/19110)のですが、その際も質問への up vote で決を採って頂きました。

Comment: CircleCiのことを余り知りませんがシノニムにはする必要はない？単に「スペースをハイフンにしただけ」だったら範囲としては大きいのでいらないかなとか思いますが、そう書いたりするのかと思って……

Comment: なるほど、どうなのでしょう……。他にも circle-ci となることがあればシノニムにして良いと思いますが、そもそも CircleCI の投稿自体少ないので、ひとまずはそこまで必要性が無いかなとは思います。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

circle-ci を circleci に変更いたしました。

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/circleci